libaio1 on Noble?
The package libaio1 is not available on Noble according to this page. Is there a replacement? I compiled it from source to make things (such as the Oracle Instant client) work on Noble, but there must be a better way.

I created a symbolic link, from libaio1t64 renamed for libaio.so.1 and my problem was solved.
Example:
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libaio.so.1t64 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libaio.so.1

But I think, its not a best of scenarios for resolve that problem.

The package in Noble is libaio1t64.  During the 24.04 cycle there was a whole migration to 64-bit time components.
libaio1 was replaced with libaio1t64 in Noble. However there's no 'transitional' packagke for libaio1 -> libaio1t64 so you may need developers of applications to update their dependencies accordingly.

I have ubuntu 24.04
Today I have installed the oracle instant client basic,and I got the error.
/usr/bin/node ./src/myapp.js
Uncaught Error Error: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "libaio.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". See https://node-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html for help
Node-oracledb installation instructions: https://node-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html
You must have Linux 64-bit Oracle Client libraries configured with ldconfig, or in LD_LIBRARY_PATH.
If you do not have Oracle Database on this computer, then install the Instant Client Basic or Basic Light package from
https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html
I solved it by creating a symbolic link from libaio.so.1t64 to libaio.so.1:
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libaio.so.1t64 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libaio.so.1
Now the application using the Oracle Instant Client on my Ubuntu system can connect to Oracle perfectly.

This is just a confirmation of https://askubuntu.com/a/1516639/158442
